# JScrollPane auto scroll down when dynamically adding JPanels

Tags: java, jscrollpane, autoscroll

I would like to scroll down a `JScrollPane` automatically when updating him. My JScrollPane contains some panels that I had time to time according to user actions.

### Tests made

**Existing solutions are all about JTextArea or JList.** The solution below works but has the problem to override every user actions (If we manually click on the ScrollBox, it will scroll down automatically after) :

```
@Override
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e){
    e.getAdjustable().setValue(e.getAdjustable().getMaximum()); 
}
```

I have tried this solution :

```
private void addPanel(JPanel newPanel){
     scrollPanel.add(newPanel);
     scrollDown(); 
}

private void scrollDown(){
    JScrollBar vertical = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
    vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
}
```

I call it just after adding a JPanel to my JScrollPane. But it scrolls not to the exact bottom but just before which is not very... clean.

Answer (score 3):

After trying to see why my second solution doesn't work completly, I printed the value (high) of the scroll bar, to see when it is updated with `scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();`

This value updates itself not immediatly after adding the JPanel, but at the next addPanel() call (so with an offset).

**I simply had to call the `revalidate()` method on my entire window** / frame to make this work.

```
private void scrollDown(){
    window.revalidate(); //Update the scrollbar size
    JScrollBar vertical = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
    vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
}
```

**Note : If you revalidate only the JScrollPane, it doesn't work.**